# Como funciona o uso de outras bases numéricas no C#?

Tags: c#, números, representação-numérica

Quando eu estava aprendendo o básico das variáveis em C#, aprendi que as declarações numéricas inteiras (`Int32`) usavam a base numérica 10, que é qual nós usamos mais comumente em nosso dia a dia. Um pouco depois, descobri que eu poderia utilizar hexadecimal para declarar variáveis `Int32`, adicionando um `0x` antes.

Com isso, minhas duvidas são:

- Como isso se comporta no compilador? Ele converte tudo para decimal antes de virar binário?
- Existem outros tipos de bases numéricas que podemos utilizar no C# sem ter que fazer conversões?

Comment: Só por curiosidade: a maioria das linguagens usa apenas base 10 e base 16, algumas permitem bases 2 e/ou 8 também. [Boolfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Boolfuck) só trabalha com base 2 e [Java2k](http://p-nand-q.com/programming/languages/java2k/) usa somente base númerica 11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É só uma sintaxe, só para o programador sentir-se mais confortável em digitar o número na forma como o domínio que ele está tratando costuma trabalhar.

Na maior parte das vezes é o decimal mesmo. Há alguns problemas típicos quando estamos lidando com coisas do computador que o hexadecimal ou binário é mais adequado. Para a aplicação é um número, não importa como ele foi representado no código. É só conveniência, não tem nada de especial. Isso nada tem a ver com tipagem.

Não existe isso de converter tudo para decimal, porque o próprio decimal é uma representação. Na verdade concretamente podemos dizer que sempre tudo é convertido para binário, que é como o computador entende. Mas é binário mesmo, são bits. O que você vê ali no código em notação binária é um texto com os caracteres `0` e `1`, não é um número binário, é só uma representação textual.

C# não adotou o octal que outras linguagens costumam ter porque ele praticamente não é usado mais na prática e costuma gerar confusão. Existem métodos que convertem textos para esta, ou a partir desta base.

Então em Hexadecimal pode representar com o prefixo `0x`  (ex.: `0xD08C`)  ou em binário com o prefixo `0b` (ex.: `0b1001_1101`), o decimal é o padrão e não precisa nada extra.

Note que é possível usar separador onde quiser em qualquer representação.

Você pode representar o mesmo número de várias formas, agora vou representar o número 3:

[image: 3 patos de borracha]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).