# Resultado de soma em binário

Tags: javascript, string, matemática, tipagem

> Um programa capaz de operar dois números binários entre 0-255. O input do programa precisa ser em binário e a saída também.

Eu fiz de uma forma que estava dando certo, de modo que, se eu passar em binário `1` + `11`, o resultado sai correto. No entanto, se eu passar `00000001` + `00000011`, o resultado é `NaN`.\

Código:

```js
function op(s, v1, v2) {
    const operator = s.toString()
    const valor1 = v1.toString()//Passei os valores para String
    const valor2 = v2.toString()

    const v1Number = parseInt(valor1, 2)//Passei de string para Number em decimal
    const v2Number = parseInt(valor2, 2)

    console.log('aqui', v1Number);
    console.log('aqui', v2Number);

    var result = 0
    switch (operator) {
        case '+':
            result = v1Number + v2Number
            console.log(result.toString(2))
            break;

        case '-':
            result = v1Number - v2Number
            console.log(result.toString(2))
            break;

        case '*':
            result = v1Number * v2Number
            console.log(result.toString(2))
            break;

        case '/':
            result = v1Number / v2Number
            console.log(result.toString(2))
            break;

        case '%':
            result = v1Number % v2Number
            console.log(result.toString(2))
            break;
    }
}
```

O que está ocorrendo:

```
op('+', 1, 11) // Funciona.

op('+', 00000001, 00000011) // Retorna `NaN`.
```

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117657/n%c3%bameros-com-inicio-zero-em-javascript

Comment: Binary-Calculator em https://codepen.io/bdemaloney/pen/MyKjov

Comment: https://ayidouble.github.io/Binary-Calculator-JavaScript/

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 6):

O conceito da questão está todo errado, não existe número binário, número é número, aritmética é aritmética, binário ou decimal é só o jeito de apresentar em tela ou papel, não se faz conta com isso. O mesmo vale para entrada de dados, se vai entrar em um formato assim, tem que fazer como texto, ou o dado é uma `string` ou ele é o texto do código.

Se você escrever `3` no seu código ele é um texto no código que nós sabemos que ele equivale à 3 unidades. Se escrever `0b00000011`, também está escrevendo um número igual, também é o que um humano entende como 3 unidades. E o computador também entende como 3, não importa como o texto foi escrito. Na verdade podemos representar um número de várias formas que nem sempre seja texto, aqui tem outra forma de dizer que tem três (opa, aqui mais uma forma de colocar em texto):

[image: 3 patos de borracha]

Se você somar a contagem nessa imagem, ou `3` com outro número, não importa em que forma foi representado, o resultado acontecerá igual.

Nunca confunda representação textual com número, você não faz conta com representação textual, só representa um número, e por isso pode usar diversas notações.

Olha a confusão do problema:

> Um programa capaz de operar dois números binários entre 0-255

Primeiro que não existem números binários, existem números que foram representados com notação binária. Os números só representam uma contagem de alguma coisa. E curiosamente o texto usa notação decimal para dizer quais são os números possíveis.

Se vai receber o dado como texto então precisa fazer uma conversão, e o JavaScript já tem uma função que faz isso, como já sabe e usou corretamente. Então primeiro converte o texto em número para depois fazer a conta. Note que não se faz a conta de um jeito especial porque recebeu um texto para representar binariamente, você converte o texto para **número**, e aí a conta é normal.

No fim manda imprimir a representação textual em notação binária do número do resultado. Se mandar imprimir sem fazer a conversão explícita o JS fará uma conversão para texto implicitamente, porque só consegue imprimir um texto que representa o número, e o padrão do JS é fazer isso na notação decimal. Se ele fosse imprimir o número de forma direta sem transformar em texto apareceria na tela algo incompreensível por um humano.

O código fica esquisito fazendo conversões sem sentido, converta só o que é necessário. Ele  pode ser muito mais simples:

```js
function op(s, v1, v2) {
    const v1Number = parseInt(v1, 2);
    const v2Number = parseInt(v2, 2);
    var result = 0;
    switch (s) {
    case '+':
        result = v1Number + v2Number;
        break;
    case '-':
        result = v1Number - v2Number;
        break;
    case '*':
        result = v1Number * v2Number;
        break;
    case '/':
        result = v1Number / v2Number;
        break;
    case '%':
        result = v1Number % v2Number;
        break;
    }
    console.log(result.toString(2));
}

op('+', '00000001', '00000011');
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/Binary.js).

Outra forma é usar a notação binária no código mas não usar o dado como binário, tratar apenas como número (entenda que está apenas dando a representação textual em binário, mas o próprio compilador converterá para número o que estava escrito em texto em notação decimal - o normal é o compilador fazer isso com a notação decimal, por isso não se engane, o que você escreve no seu código é só um texto, não é um número, você sabe que ele virará número na compilação, ao contrário do código acima que a conversão é feita em execução):

```js
function op(s, v1Number, v2Number) {
    var result = 0;
    switch (s) {
    case '+':
        result = v1Number + v2Number;
        break;
    case '-':
        result = v1Number - v2Number;
        break;
    case '*':
        result = v1Number * v2Number;
        break;
    case '/':
        result = v1Number / v2Number;
        break;
    case '%':
        result = v1Number % v2Number;
        break;
    }
    console.log(result.toString(2));
}

op('+', 0b00000001, 0b00000011);
op('+', 1, 3); //note que funciona igual
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Math/Binary.js).

Soltarei rojões o dia que as pessoas entenderem que número é número, é diferente de um texto que mostra o que deveria ser esse número. Notação decimal, binária ou hexadecimal não são números, são textos de como escreve o número. Então cuidado, muito exercício, artigo, ou respostas que encontrará por aí é dada por quem não quis entender esse conceito corretamente e fará você entender errado também, esse mito precisa acabar.

Veja mais em:

- [Como funcionam os números em hexadecimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13573/101)
- [O que são números de notação Decimal, Hexadecimal e Octal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47854/101)
- [Números com inicio zero em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/117657/101)
- [Conversão decimal em binário em linguagem C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216128/101)
- [Como funciona o uso de outras bases numéricas no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/224879/101)
- [Como converter binário em decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152947/101)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @AlbertoBelo veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.

Comment: @AlbertoBelo, a melhor maneira de agradecer é marcar a resposta como aceita, veja como https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png

Comment: @AlbertoBelo Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 